# Detection of chessboard-like pattern in OpenCV

Tags: chess, calibration

I have a problem with detection of chessboard-like pattern. The image is very noisy because it is registered with the use of laser scanner.

[image: Example image]

The only thing I have managed to achieve is detection of big rectangle:
[image]

Now I have no idea how to detect those small squares. I tried all sorts of different algorithms, but the contrast in the squares seems too low. Does anybody have any ideas?

Other pattern images: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3681534/kalibrator/6.png https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3681534/kalibrator/8.png

Answer (score 0):

A way to progress would be to determine the `grayvalue` level at the inner border of the rectangle, then:

1. Adjust the average brightness inside the rectangle border.
2. With that knowledge it is possible to adjust the average brightness inside the rectangle to one value (the small square will still be a bit lighter than the rest)
3. Increase the contrast a lot
4. Find the lines that run along the edges of the squares
5. Either access the line crossings directly or paint white and black
6. Calculate your calibration data